# installing features WSO2 Carbon server

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2, saml, authenticator

I would like to install org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.server_4.1.0.jar features for carbon server 4.1.0. 
I downloaded the P2 repository and I added it in the features management.
The problem is that it can't find this feature.
Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

SAML2 Authenticator is included in carbon products by default. You do not have to install it.